# Provide constructive answer rather than "attacking" the question

Tags: discussion

Sometimes questions are ill-posed (e.g. no minimal reproducible example or few specifications), but they might still be easy enough to be answered with little effort.

As an example, consider this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122163/how-to-subtract-2-columns-in-2-different-dataframes-of-different-sizes-based-on/41122294#41122294

To me, the answer is quite straightforward, and hopefully my answer will help me not only solve the problem, but also show the OP how they should have posed the question in the first place.

Do you think this is the correct way of proceeding?

I think SO is a great way of learning, and there are memorable questions and answers that required much effort as they are meant to clarify a concept to many people.

Other questions are simply to ask for help with a specific problem, and I feel giving a simple answer might encourage the OP to follow rules in the future more than a downvote, flag, or link to documentation.

Comment: And… why exactly would giving in to what they want make them more likely to follow the rules?

Comment: Also, meta-effect.

Comment: if it isn't following the rules, it has to be closed. If you give people what they want without extra effort they won't follow the rules.

Comment: The site gets 12,000+ new questions each day, many of them really bad. Sternly admonishing each, and then giving a full answer would be a fool's errand - especially since it is super easy to just create a new account and ask the next lazy question that looks like it's from a total newbie. It would create even more frustration than there already is for those who create value around here by answering questions

Comment: Absolutely not. The question should be closed (And possibly even deleted), and I've edited out your comment in the answer. Don't add meta-information like that in a answer.

Comment: We don't want _easy to answer_, we want high quality.

Comment: Is the question being downvoted because the answer is "no" or because there is something wrong with the question?

Comment: @FLab Most likely the former. Voting on meta typically indicates agreement or disagreement on [meta-tag:discussion] questions.

Comment: Downvoting, flagging, and commenting are ***not*** ways of "attacking" a question. It seems that this is your central misconception.

Comment: Wait, 3 different possible duplicates?

Comment: @StephenLeppik - I'm not surprised. I was about to respond to FLab's comment with, "I'm pretty sure this is a dupe".

Answer (score 22):

> Do you think it is correct way of proceeding?

No, absolutely not.

SO is designed to be a useful repository of knowledge where people can find high quality, well-answered questions. Filling the site with low quality, unclear, inappropriately scoped, etc. questions with wild guesses that may or may not relate to the question and that spend much of their effort trying to teach the question author how to properly ask a question *aren't useful to other people* (and are very often not even useful to the one asking the question).

When you see someone asking a low quality question you should be helping them improve their question into an acceptable question, and then *after* they have turned the question into a good question, *then* you should be answering it.

There are *lots* of tools that you have available to you to help you improve questions.  You can comment on them to explain their problems or how they can be improved, you can vote to close them to indicate what's wrong and to prevent low quality answers like the ones you've been posting from being posted to a question that's not yet in a state where it can be given a quality answer, you can downvote it to indicate to the author, the system itself, an other readers that the question is not yet up to par, you can edit the question to fix certain types of problems (i.e. presentation, formatting, removing noise, etc.).

Comment: _then you should be answering it_ - unless it turns out to be a duplicate of another question - then it should be closed as such and still not be answered (again).